# Any way to pull likes by dates from facebook graph api? (New Likes instaed of Global Likes)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I basically need an access to a fanpage's likes by dates, i mean.. not the global likes when you access the graph but the ability to see how much likes the page got yesterday/today..

Any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/#page_users - you (by which I mean the user of your app) need to be admin of the page though. You get page_fans, *_adds, *_removes, etc.. On how to execute FQL using the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/